# KrisFlyer miles when booking a ticket for someone else

Tags: loyalty-programs, singapore-airlines, miles-and-more

I used my KrisFlyer account to add my girlfriend as a redemption nominee and used my miles to buy a ticket on Singapore Airlines for her. She used her credit card to pay the remaining fare.

In this case, who gets the KrisFlyer miles for the flight she will take? Does she need to do anything to get them credited to herself or if we do nothing, will they be credited to my account even though I am not flying? It doesn't matter who gets it but wondering how Singapore Airlines credits miles in this sort of case. She also has a Miles and More card.

Comment: Do you mean miles for the award flight? As far as I know, nobody gets any miles on those.

Comment: @jcaron yes. It was paid with a combination of miles + cash (and most of it was cash). So is it not itself eligible for miles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at Singapore Airlines' KrisFlyer Terms and Conditions, it appears that the answer to your question is "Neither of you will earn miles for the portion of her ticket that was charged to her credit card."

Singapore Airlines' [KrisFlyer webpage](https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/us/ppsclub-krisflyer/use-miles/mix-miles-and-cash/) contains this text:

> For Mix KrisFlyer miles and cash bookings, the number of KrisFlyer miles, Elite miles and PPS Value you earn will be in proportion to the amount that you've paid with your credit/debit card (excluding taxes). If the full amount is paid with KrisFlyer miles, no KrisFlyer miles, Elite miles and PPS Value will be earned. Read more in [FAQs](https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/sg/faqCategory/?category=34700).

The FAQ cited above contains this question on Page 2:

> Will I earn KrisFlyer miles, Elite miles, and PPS Value if I mix KrisFlyer miles and cash for my:
>
> ...

The page goes on to list different factual scenarios in which miles and money are used to obtain tickets. Subsection (b) applies here:

> ...
>
> (b) fare on Singapore Airlines or SilkAir for my redemption nominee(s) only?
> **No, you won’t earn miles when you’re not a passenger in the same booking. If your redemption nominee is a KrisFlyer or PPS Club member, he/she will earn KrisFlyer miles, Elite miles and PPS Value on eligible fares. KrisFlyer miles, Elite miles and PPS Value will be earned in proportion to the amount (excluding taxes) that *you* have paid with *your* credit/debit card.**  [emphasis added]
>
> ...

Thus, you must be a passenger to earn miles. Your nominee will earn miles only if the money part of the ticket was paid for using your credit card, not hers.